# pass data to directive controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I got problem with AngularJS. I got data in JSON file. I got also service which is responsible for retrieving data from that file. After getting data, I would like to pass it to my directive, but I always got undefined (when I'm passing constant value, like string - not from file - it works). My code:

HTML:

```
<experience-timeline ng-model="experience"/>
```

Controller:

```
myAppCvExperienceModule.controller('ExperienceCtrl', function ($scope, dataService) {

    dataService.getExpJson().success(function (res) {
        $scope.experience = res;
    });

});
```

Directive:

```
myAppModule.directive('experienceTimeline', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: ['ngModel'],
    scope: {
        ngModel: '=ngModel'
    },
    controller : function($scope) {
        console.log($scope.ngModel); // always undefined
    },
    templateUrl: 'scripts/directives/experience-timeline/template/experience-timeline.html'
}
});
```

Why should I always got undefined? How to pass data correctly?

Comment: The controller is instantiated, and thus the console.log() executed, **before** the success callback of your $http call is invoked. $http calls are asynchronous. Add a button with an ng-click to your directive template, and log the value from the ng-click function, and it should be there. Don't use ngModel to pass data to a directive. Use any other attribute name. That only makes things confusing.

Comment: That's true. But it doesn't solve my problem, because I would like to perform some calculations (but I always got undefined) in directive controller. Of course I can get data from json in directive controller, but I don't want to do that.

Comment: My point is: you need to wait for the data to be there to be able to perform calculations. So watch the scope variable, or only include the directive in the page (using ng-if) once the data is available.